# Displaying the total number of adjacent pairs in this program

Tags: c, string, for-loop, count, repeat

Given an input `char[]` I would like to find the number of discrete pairs in the string. So for an input of:

- `"dddd"` the output is 2 pairs
- `"ddd"` the output is 1 pair
- `"dd"` the output is 1 pair
- `"d"` the output is 0 pairs

The characters in each pair must be adjacent. For an input of `"abca"` the output is still 0 because the `'a'`s are not adjacent.[*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692645/displaying-the-total-number-of-adjacent-pairs-in-this-program?#comment53229099_32692645)

The goal is to find the total number of pairs in the string. So for an input of `"aaxbb"` the output should be 2.[*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32692645/displaying-the-total-number-of-adjacent-pairs-in-this-program?#comment53241307_32692645)

For my input string of `char a[] = "dppccddd"` there are 3 pairs of adjacent letters but [my program's output is 4](http://ideone.com/xLn4xO). How do I solve the problem?

```
int i = 0, count = 0, count1 = 0;

for (i = 0; i <= 6; i++)
{
    if (a[i] == a[i + 1])
    count++;
}
printf("%d", count);
```

Comment: Ok, so what is your problem?

Comment: i want to display the number of pairs. Only even pairs, must be displayed.

if ddd= pair is 1
if dddd= pair is 2
if ddddd pair is 2

Comment: I got that from the description. What is your question? Does something not work? Be more descriptive

Comment: The logic I've written is to display total number of pairs in a string. So there is a error in the logical part.

Comment: There are a few problems with your code actually... Just count the frequency of each letter and do integer division by 2. Your code only looks at adjacent elements

Comment: May I know what is that?

Comment: So If you had ['a','b','c','a'] It wouldn't match 'a' as a pair

Comment: I believe the problem is, that it counts the sequence of three 'd' twice, isn't it?

Comment: @RefugnicEternium well there are a lot of problems, as I said :) At the very least jump one more character further If characters are matched

Comment: @akalikin: Yeah, if ['a','b',c','a'] is given, it won't be matched.

Comment: what is the correct program then?

Comment: Try changing `if(a[i]==a[i+1])
        count++;` to `if(a[i]==a[i+1])
        {count++; i++;}`

Comment: And here we are, discussing this. But I'm still not 100% Sure what the question is.

Comment: @akalikin: I want help for the code. That's the question.

Comment: @SurabhiGowdaK Do you want your code to print 3 or 4? And if `['a','b',c','a']` was the array, do you want your program to print 1 or 2?

Comment: @cool guy: It prints nothing as there is no adjacent pair.

Comment: @SurabhiGowdaK The problem with the question is that it's not clear what exactly you need the code to do. You never said what your problem with your code is. In your code you only count adjacent elements(Wrongly) (a,a,b,c,d) will output 1, (a,b,c,a) will not. Right now this is low quality question

Comment: @SurabhiGowdaK Doesn't changing `if(a[i]==a[i+1]) count++;` to `if(a[i]==a[i+1]) {count++; i++;}` fix the problem?

Comment: @CoolGuy Yes, it will in this case

Comment: @CoolGuy: It helped! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @SurabhiGowdaK Your example string has the sequence `'p', 'p', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd'` should that print as 3 pairs in a row? Or is that just 1 pair?

Comment: @SurabhiGowdaK Additionally I'd appreciate if you could clarify whether oddly repeating characters should break the count: `'p', 'p', 'p', 'c', 'c'` should that print 1 par or 2 pairs?

Comment: @JonathanMee: {'p','p','c','c','d','d'} should be printed as 3 pairs
{'p','p','p','c','c'} should be printed as 2 pairs

Comment: @JDS I think [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32694757/2642059) has covered all the cases. I'm basing this on the fact that you say you're looking for "pairs of adjacent letters". I'm interpreting this to mean that `'a', 'a', 'x', 'b', 'b'` should print 1 is that correct?

Comment: @JonathanMee: It should print as 2. coolguy suggested the answer i was looking for!

Comment: @JDS I see, yeah that's a lot simpler if you just want the total number of pairs. Beware that you don't read out of bounds with that answer.

Answer (score 3):

Just to make your code slightly better, 
instead of hardcoding value of 6, use `for(i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]) - 1; i++)`
To get a number of elements in an array.

The problem with your code is that if two chars are matched, it will start comparing from the second one again, you need to skip that character, so increase `i` by 1:

```
if(a[i] == a[i + 1]) {
    ++count;
    ++i;
}
```

Comment: This has two problems: 1. Segfaults if `a` is size 0 2. Does not reset the count upon non-adjacent letters `'a', 'a', 'x', 'b', 'b'` Instead it would report 2 for this: http://ideone.com/wO51Ol

Comment: Change the for loop to `for (i=0; i<(sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]) - 2); i++)`.

Comment: @acw1668 Doesn't work what if the last character would increment the pair count?

Comment: @acw1668 It is not right that this loop is correct, as stated in my previous comment it segfaults when the size of `a` is 0. The correct loop is in my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32694757/2642059

Comment: @JonathanMee, I did not get segfault using @Amir for loop and got correct answers for `a[] = {}` and `a[] = { 'd', 'd' }`.

Comment: @acw1668 http://ideone.com/f6neCP The problem is that `sizeof` returns an `size_t` which is `unsigned`. Essentially this has set the upper bound of the loop to be `0U - 1` which is a *very* large number, definitely bigger than the size of `a`.

Comment: @JonathanMee, you are right.  As my code use an int variable to store the number of elements in the array: `int num = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);` and then use this variable in the for loop: `for (i=0; i<num-1; ++i)`.  This will not have the problem you stated.

Answer (score 2):

### For adjacent cells:

All you have to do is jump by one additional step if you find a pair, as @Cool Guy mentioned:

`if(a[i]==a[i+1]) {count++; i++;}`

---

### For not only adjacent cells:

The easiest way to solve the case when you want to compare not only adjacent cells is to count every character frequency in a separate array and then check if those frequencies are divisable by 2.

**How to build an array of frequencies?**

If you only store a-z letters in your first array, the second one needs to have 26 cells (for a-z letters). First: set all cells of `freq[26]` to 0. Then, for every cell in the first array `a[]`, increment valid cell:

```
freq[0]++; // i found letter 'a'
freq[4]++; // i found letter 'e'
```

**How to know which cells in freq[] should I increment?**

Pro-tip: you can find out which cell to increment by writing `freq[ a[i]-'a' ]++;`. Why?

If `a[i]` is 'a', then `a[i]-'a'` gives you 0,
if `a[i]` is 'c', then `a[i]-'a'` gives you 2 etc.

Comment: See the latest OP's comments to his question. This is the reason why I didn't post an answer, he doesn't want to consider all chars in an array, he only needs adjacent ones

Answer (score 0):

## Do not use a `for` loop

Since you'll be implementing a greedy approach, you need more control on the indexing variable, therefore use a **`while`** loop instead.

## Increment your index variable

For a correct "exclusive pairs" counting, you need to increment it each time a pair is found.

## Beware of edge cases

You  have to iterate until **`sizeof(a) - 1`**, because you don't want to fall out of index.

## Keep it simple and succinct

Time complexity: *O(n)*.
Space complexity: *O(1)*.

```
int count = 0;
int i = -1;
char a[] = "dppccddd";

while(++i < sizeof(a) - 1)
{
    if (a[i] == a[i + 1])
    {
        count++;
        i++;
    }
}
printf("Pairs count is: %d", count);
```

[Live demo.](http://ideone.com/1SwLGw)

Answer (score -2):

The answers to this question given by [Amir](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32693451/2642059) and [Mateusz Kwasniak](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32693155/2642059) are correct but they both segfault on zero-sized `a`s: http://ideone.com/BoxocM

A better solution is to control the increment and look behind *not* ahead:

```
int i = 1;
int count = 0;
char a[] = "dppccddd";

while(i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])) {
    if(a[i - 1] == a[i]) {
        ++count;
        i += 2;
    } else {
        ++i;
    }
}

printf("%d", count);
```

[[Live Example](http://ideone.com/81bBeM)]

This will not segfault on any size `a`, and will provide identical results on non-zero sized `a`s.

Comment: You just completely disregarded pars of 'p' and 'c'. Output should be `3` not `1`

Comment: @Amir Yeah I did I misunderstood the question. I have edited.

Comment: Nope. still wrong. try char a[]={'d', 'p', 'p', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd', 'a','a','a','a'}; - outputs 3, not 5

Comment: @Amir Interesting problem. I understand now, does that not error on your solution as well?

Comment: @Amir In thinking about it, I'm uncertain. Should that be 5? `'d', 'a'` is certainly not a discrete pair.