# Find the Number of Pairs that are Repeated in a List

Tags: c, arrays, string, char, repeat

Given an arbitrary `char[]` find the number of character pairs in the string. So this would be 3:

> aabbcc

If two pairs of the same character adjacent both pairs should be counted. So this would be 3:

> aaaabb

An interrupting single `char` must reset the count of consecutive character pairs. So this would be 1:

> aabcc

If the interrupting single char is the same as the preceding pair it does *not* reset the count of consecutive character pairs. So this would be 3:

> aabbbccc

---

This is an adaptation from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32692645/2642059). The original interpretation of the question was interesting but the comments kept changing the nature of that question from it's original interpretation. [This was my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32715325/2642059) to that original interpretation, and I was wondering if improvement could be made upon it?

Answer (score 1):

Loop control should use the size of the array for the range, and indexing of `a[i + 1]` may be out of bounds if `i` is the index to the last element, so using `a[i - 1]` instead and iterating over the range [`1` .. `sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])`] is preferable

The algorithm is best solved with 3 variables:

- `char* last` points to the first element of the current string of consecutive characters
- `int count1` the number of consecutive pairs in the current count
- `int count` the highest number of recorded consecutive pairs

The algorithm is best illustrated with a state machine. It will operate on :

[image: State Machine]

1. Upon entry set `last` to `NULL`, if `count1` is larger than `count` assign `count1` to `count`, and reset `count1` to `0`
2. Upon entry set `last` to the first character in this string of consecutive characters (`a[i-1]`)
3. Upon entry add the number of consecutive characters pointed to by last divided by 2 so as to only find the pairs

This is corrected code with comments inline:

```
size_t i = 0;
char* last = NULL;
long int count1 = 0;
long int count = 0;
char a[] = {'d', 'p', 'p', 'c', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'd'};

while (++i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])) { // This will iterate over the range: [1 .. sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])]
    if (a[i - 1] == a[i]) { // Test previous character to avoid going out of range
        if (last == NULL) { // Entry to state 2
            last = a + i - 1;
        }
    } else if (last != NULL) {
        if (a + i - last > 1) { // Entry to state 3 
            count1 += (a + i - last) / 2;
            last = a + i;
        } else { // Entry to state 1
            if (count1 > count) { // If the current count is larger
                count = count1; // Replace the maximum count
            }
            count1 = 0; // Reset the current count
            last = NULL;
        }
    }
}

if (last != NULL) { // Entry to state 3
    if (a + (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])) - last > 1) {
        count1 += (a + (sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0])) - last) / 2;
    }

    if (count1 > count) { // If the current count is larger
        count = count1; // Replace the maximum count
    }
}

printf("%ld", count);
```

[[Live Example](http://ideone.com/yPuIuc)]

Comment: You declared **i** as int but you are comparing it with an unsingned (sizeof) then **count** was declared as int and here **count1 += (a + i - last) / 2; **error: conversion to ‘int’ from ‘long int’ may alter its value**

Comment: @Michi Interesting, that would make sense that the conversion would fail on a 64-bit machine. I guess http://www.ideone.com must still be 32-bit cause I didn't have any problems. In either case I believe I have fixed it, thanks for the tip.

Comment: UpONE for the way how you explain it and yes now compiles fine.